# JBoss developer studio/GWT gwt-kitchensink fails to compile

Tags: gwt, jboss, compiler-errors

I'm running Windows 8 release preview and have 32-bit JRE7 installed. I downloaded Jboss Developer Studio and installed it. After that installed Google eclipse plugin and GWT and followed the steps as shown in this video. [7. JBoss Developer Studio with GWT on Vimeo](http://vimeo.com/39743919)

I do this step

Run As > Maven Build and provide Goals=package and Run. The compilation fails. I cannot understand the problem, how to solve it?

Below are the the messages that appear in Console of Eclipse:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building JBoss AS Quickstarts: Errai kitchensink 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3:resources (default-resources) @ gwt-kitchensink ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 4 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- gwt-maven-plugin:2.4.0:resources (default) @ gwt-kitchensink ---
[INFO] auto discovered modules [org.jboss.tools.gwt.kitchensink.KitchenSink]
[INFO] 10 source files from GWT module org.jboss.tools.gwt.kitchensink.KitchenSink
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ gwt-kitchensink ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3:testResources (default-testResources) @ gwt-kitchensink ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ gwt-kitchensink ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.4.3:test (default-test) @ gwt-kitchensink ---
[INFO] Tests are skipped.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- gwt-maven-plugin:2.4.0:compile (default) @ gwt-kitchensink ---
[INFO] auto discovered modules [org.jboss.tools.gwt.kitchensink.KitchenSink]
[WARNING] Don't declare gwt-dev as a project dependency. This may introduce complex dependency conflicts
[INFO] Compiling module org.jboss.tools.gwt.kitchensink.KitchenSink
[INFO]    Validating newly compiled units
[INFO]       Ignored 6 units with compilation errors in first pass.
[INFO] Compile with -strict or with -logLevel set to TRACE or DEBUG to see all errors.
[INFO]    Scanning for additional dependencies: jar:file:/D:/Users/Icemilk/.m2/repository/org/jboss/errai/errai-ioc/2.0.0.Final/errai-ioc-2.0.0.Final.jar!/org/jboss/errai/ioc/client/Container.java
[INFO]       Computing all possible rebind results for 'org.jboss.errai.ioc.client.Bootstrapper'
[INFO]          Rebinding org.jboss.errai.ioc.client.Bootstrapper
[INFO]             Invoking generator org.jboss.errai.ioc.rebind.ioc.bootstrapper.IOCGenerator
[INFO]                Generating Extensions Bootstrapper...
[ERROR] log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.jboss.errai.ioc.rebind.ioc.bootstrapper.IOCBootstrapGenerator).
[ERROR] log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
[ERROR] log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
[INFO]                Checking ErraiApp.properties for configured types ...
[INFO]          Rebinding org.jboss.errai.ioc.client.Bootstrapper
[INFO]             Invoking generator org.jboss.errai.ioc.rebind.ioc.bootstrapper.IOCGenerator
[INFO]                Generating Extensions Bootstrapper...
[INFO]          Rebinding org.jboss.errai.ioc.client.Bootstrapper
[INFO]             Invoking generator org.jboss.errai.ioc.rebind.ioc.bootstrapper.IOCGenerator
[INFO]                Generating Extensions Bootstrapper...
[INFO]          Rebinding org.jboss.errai.ioc.client.Bootstrapper
[INFO]             Invoking generator org.jboss.errai.ioc.rebind.ioc.bootstrapper.IOCGenerator
[INFO]                Generating Extensions Bootstrapper...
[INFO]          Rebinding org.jboss.errai.ioc.client.Bootstrapper
[INFO]             Invoking generator org.jboss.errai.ioc.rebind.ioc.bootstrapper.IOCGenerator
[INFO]                Generating Extensions Bootstrapper...
[INFO]          Rebinding org.jboss.errai.ioc.client.Bootstrapper
[INFO]             Invoking generator org.jboss.errai.ioc.rebind.ioc.bootstrapper.IOCGenerator
[INFO]                Generating Extensions Bootstrapper...
[INFO]    Scanning for additional dependencies: jar:file:/D:/Users/Icemilk/.m2/repository/org/jboss/errai/errai-marshalling/2.0.0.Final/errai-marshalling-2.0.0.Final.jar!/org/jboss/errai/marshalling/client/api/MarshallerFramework.java
[INFO]       Computing all possible rebind results for 'org.jboss.errai.marshalling.client.api.MarshallerFactory'
[INFO]          Rebinding org.jboss.errai.marshalling.client.api.MarshallerFactory
[INFO]             Invoking generator org.jboss.errai.marshalling.rebind.MarshallersGenerator
[INFO]                Generating Marshallers Bootstrapper...
[INFO] *** FAILED TO COMPILE MARSHALLER CLASS ***
[INFO] *** Classpath Used: D:\Project\7th Semester\JBoss Developer Studio\Workspace\gwt-kitchensink\src\main\resources;D:\Project\7th Semester\JBoss Developer Studio\Workspace\gwt-kitchensink\target\classes;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\org\jboss\errai\errai-bus\2.0.0.Final\errai-bus-2.0.0.Final.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\org\jboss\errai\errai-marshalling\2.0.0.Final\errai-marshalling-2.0.0.Final.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\org\jboss\errai\errai-ioc\2.0.0.Final\errai-ioc-2.0.0.Final.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\org\jboss\errai\errai-tools\2.0.0.Final\errai-tools-2.0.0.Final.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\org\jboss\errai\errai-cdi-client\2.0.0.Final\errai-cdi-client-2.0.0.Final.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\org\jboss\errai\errai-weld-integration\2.0.0.Final\errai-weld-integration-2.0.0.Final.jar;D:\Project\7th Semester\JBoss Developer Studio\Workspace\gwt-kitchensink\src\main\java;D:\Project\7th Semester\JBoss Developer Studio\Workspace\gwt-kitchensink\src\main\resources;D:\Project\7th Semester\JBoss Developer Studio\Workspace\gwt-kitchensink\target\classes;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\javax\enterprise\cdi-api\1.0-SP4\cdi-api-1.0-SP4.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\org\jboss\spec\javax\interceptor\jboss-interceptors-api_1.1_spec\1.0.1.Final\jboss-interceptors-api_1.1_spec-1.0.1.Final.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\javax\inject\javax.inject\1\javax.inject-1.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\org\jboss\spec\javax\transaction\jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec\1.0.1.Final\jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec-1.0.1.Final.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\org\jboss\spec\javax\annotation\jboss-annotations-api_1.1_spec\1.0.1.Final\jboss-annotations-api_1.1_spec-1.0.1.Final.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\org\jboss\spec\javax\ws\rs\jboss-jaxrs-api_1.1_spec\1.0.0.Final\jboss-jaxrs-api_1.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\javax\persistence\hibernate-jpa-2.0-api\1.0.1.Final\hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\org\jboss\spec\javax\ejb\jboss-ejb-api_3.1_spec\1.0.2.Final\jboss-ejb-api_3.1_spec-1.0.2.Final.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\javax\validation\validation-api\1.0.0.GA\validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-validator\4.2.0.Final\hibernate-validator-4.2.0.Final.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-validator\4.2.0.Final\hibernate-validator-4.2.0.Final-sources.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\javax\validation\validation-api\1.0.0.GA\validation-api-1.0.0.GA-sources.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\org\jboss\errai\errai-bus\2.0.0.Final\errai-bus-2.0.0.Final.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\org\jboss\errai\errai-common\2.0.0.Final\errai-common-2.0.0.Final.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\org\jboss\errai\reflections\reflections\2.0.0.Final\reflections-2.0.0.Final.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\com\google\guava\guava\10.0.1\guava-10.0.1.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\com\google\code\findbugs\jsr305\1.3.9\jsr305-1.3.9.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\dom4j\dom4j\1.6.1\dom4j-1.6.1.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\xml-apis\xml-apis\1.0.b2\xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\org\jboss\errai\errai-marshalling\2.0.0.Final\errai-marshalling-2.0.0.Final.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\com\google\inject\guice\3.0\guice-3.0.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\aopalliance\aopalliance\1.0\aopalliance-1.0.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\org\mvel\mvel2\2.1.Beta8\mvel2-2.1.Beta8.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.6.1\slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-log4j12\1.6.1\slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\log4j\log4j\1.2.16\log4j-1.2.16.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\org\javassist\javassist\3.15.0-GA\javassist-3.15.0-GA.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\org\jboss\errai\io\netty\netty\4.0.0.Alpha1.errai.r1\netty-4.0.0.Alpha1.errai.r1.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\org\jboss\errai\errai-ioc\2.0.0.Final\errai-ioc-2.0.0.Final.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\org\jboss\errai\errai-codegen\2.0.0.Final\errai-codegen-2.0.0.Final.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\org\jboss\errai\errai-tools\2.0.0.Final\errai-tools-2.0.0.Final.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\hsqldb\hsqldb\1.8.0.7\hsqldb-1.8.0.7.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\org\jboss\errai\errai-cdi-client\2.0.0.Final\errai-cdi-client-2.0.0.Final.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\org\jboss\errai\errai-javax-enterprise\2.0.0.Final\errai-javax-enterprise-2.0.0.Final.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\org\jboss\errai\errai-weld-integration\2.0.0.Final\errai-weld-integration-2.0.0.Final.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\com\google\gwt\gwt-user\2.4.0\gwt-user-2.4.0.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\com\google\gwt\gwt-dev\2.4.0\gwt-dev-2.4.0.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-jpamodelgen\1.1.1.Final\hibernate-jpamodelgen-1.1.1.Final.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\com\google\gwt\gwt-user\2.4.0\gwt-user-2.4.0.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\javax\validation\validation-api\1.0.0.GA\validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\javax\validation\validation-api\1.0.0.GA\validation-api-1.0.0.GA-sources.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\com\google\gwt\gwt-dev\2.4.0\gwt-dev-2.4.0.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\javax\enterprise\cdi-api\1.0-SP4\cdi-api-1.0-SP4.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\org\jboss\spec\javax\interceptor\jboss-interceptors-api_1.1_spec\1.0.1.Final\jboss-interceptors-api_1.1_spec-1.0.1.Final.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\org\jboss\spec\javax\transaction\jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec\1.0.1.Final\jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec-1.0.1.Final.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\org\jboss\spec\javax\annotation\jboss-annotations-api_1.1_spec\1.0.1.Final\jboss-annotations-api_1.1_spec-1.0.1.Final.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\org\jboss\spec\javax\ws\rs\jboss-jaxrs-api_1.1_spec\1.0.0.Final\jboss-jaxrs-api_1.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\javax\persistence\hibernate-jpa-2.0-api\1.0.1.Final\hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\org\jboss\spec\javax\ejb\jboss-ejb-api_3.1_spec\1.0.2.Final\jboss-ejb-api_3.1_spec-1.0.2.Final.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\javax\validation\validation-api\1.0.0.GA\validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-validator\4.2.0.Final\hibernate-validator-4.2.0.Final.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-validator\4.2.0.Final\hibernate-validator-4.2.0.Final-sources.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\javax\validation\validation-api\1.0.0.GA\validation-api-1.0.0.GA-sources.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\org\jboss\errai\errai-bus\2.0.0.Final\errai-bus-2.0.0.Final.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\org\jboss\errai\errai-common\2.0.0.Final\errai-common-2.0.0.Final.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\org\jboss\errai\reflections\reflections\2.0.0.Final\reflections-2.0.0.Final.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\com\google\guava\guava\10.0.1\guava-10.0.1.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\com\google\code\findbugs\jsr305\1.3.9\jsr305-1.3.9.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\dom4j\dom4j\1.6.1\dom4j-1.6.1.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\xml-apis\xml-apis\1.0.b2\xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\org\jboss\errai\errai-marshalling\2.0.0.Final\errai-marshalling-2.0.0.Final.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\com\google\inject\guice\3.0\guice-3.0.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\aopalliance\aopalliance\1.0\aopalliance-1.0.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\org\mvel\mvel2\2.1.Beta8\mvel2-2.1.Beta8.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.6.1\slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-log4j12\1.6.1\slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\log4j\log4j\1.2.16\log4j-1.2.16.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\org\javassist\javassist\3.15.0-GA\javassist-3.15.0-GA.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\org\jboss\errai\io\netty\netty\4.0.0.Alpha1.errai.r1\netty-4.0.0.Alpha1.errai.r1.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\org\jboss\errai\errai-ioc\2.0.0.Final\errai-ioc-2.0.0.Final.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\org\jboss\errai\errai-codegen\2.0.0.Final\errai-codegen-2.0.0.Final.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\org\jboss\errai\errai-tools\2.0.0.Final\errai-tools-2.0.0.Final.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\hsqldb\hsqldb\1.8.0.7\hsqldb-1.8.0.7.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\org\jboss\errai\errai-cdi-client\2.0.0.Final\errai-cdi-client-2.0.0.Final.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\org\jboss\errai\errai-javax-enterprise\2.0.0.Final\errai-javax-enterprise-2.0.0.Final.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\org\jboss\errai\errai-weld-integration\2.0.0.Final\errai-weld-integration-2.0.0.Final.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\com\google\gwt\gwt-user\2.4.0\gwt-user-2.4.0.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\com\google\gwt\gwt-dev\2.4.0\gwt-dev-2.4.0.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-jpamodelgen\1.1.1.Final\hibernate-jpamodelgen-1.1.1.Final.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\javax\enterprise\cdi-api\1.0-SP4\cdi-api-1.0-SP4.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\org\jboss\spec\javax\interceptor\jboss-interceptors-api_1.1_spec\1.0.1.Final\jboss-interceptors-api_1.1_spec-1.0.1.Final.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\org\jboss\spec\javax\transaction\jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec\1.0.1.Final\jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec-1.0.1.Final.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\org\jboss\spec\javax\annotation\jboss-annotations-api_1.1_spec\1.0.1.Final\jboss-annotations-api_1.1_spec-1.0.1.Final.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\org\jboss\spec\javax\ws\rs\jboss-jaxrs-api_1.1_spec\1.0.0.Final\jboss-jaxrs-api_1.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\javax\persistence\hibernate-jpa-2.0-api\1.0.1.Final\hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\org\jboss\spec\javax\ejb\jboss-ejb-api_3.1_spec\1.0.2.Final\jboss-ejb-api_3.1_spec-1.0.2.Final.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\javax\validation\validation-api\1.0.0.GA\validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-validator\4.2.0.Final\hibernate-validator-4.2.0.Final.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-validator\4.2.0.Final\hibernate-validator-4.2.0.Final-sources.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\javax\validation\validation-api\1.0.0.GA\validation-api-1.0.0.GA-sources.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\org\jboss\errai\errai-bus\2.0.0.Final\errai-bus-2.0.0.Final.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\org\jboss\errai\errai-common\2.0.0.Final\errai-common-2.0.0.Final.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\org\jboss\errai\reflections\reflections\2.0.0.Final\reflections-2.0.0.Final.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\com\google\guava\guava\10.0.1\guava-10.0.1.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\com\google\code\findbugs\jsr305\1.3.9\jsr305-1.3.9.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\dom4j\dom4j\1.6.1\dom4j-1.6.1.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\xml-apis\xml-apis\1.0.b2\xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\org\jboss\errai\errai-marshalling\2.0.0.Final\errai-marshalling-2.0.0.Final.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\com\google\inject\guice\3.0\guice-3.0.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\aopalliance\aopalliance\1.0\aopalliance-1.0.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\org\mvel\mvel2\2.1.Beta8\mvel2-2.1.Beta8.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.6.1\slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-log4j12\1.6.1\slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\log4j\log4j\1.2.16\log4j-1.2.16.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\org\javassist\javassist\3.15.0-GA\javassist-3.15.0-GA.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\org\jboss\errai\io\netty\netty\4.0.0.Alpha1.errai.r1\netty-4.0.0.Alpha1.errai.r1.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\org\jboss\errai\errai-ioc\2.0.0.Final\errai-ioc-2.0.0.Final.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\org\jboss\errai\errai-codegen\2.0.0.Final\errai-codegen-2.0.0.Final.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\org\jboss\errai\errai-tools\2.0.0.Final\errai-tools-2.0.0.Final.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\hsqldb\hsqldb\1.8.0.7\hsqldb-1.8.0.7.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\org\jboss\errai\errai-cdi-client\2.0.0.Final\errai-cdi-client-2.0.0.Final.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\org\jboss\errai\errai-javax-enterprise\2.0.0.Final\errai-javax-enterprise-2.0.0.Final.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\org\jboss\errai\errai-weld-integration\2.0.0.Final\errai-weld-integration-2.0.0.Final.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\com\google\gwt\gwt-user\2.4.0\gwt-user-2.4.0.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\com\google\gwt\gwt-dev\2.4.0\gwt-dev-2.4.0.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-jpamodelgen\1.1.1.Final\hibernate-jpamodelgen-1.1.1.Final.jar
[INFO] Unrecognized option : Semester\JBoss
[INFO]          Rebinding org.jboss.errai.marshalling.client.api.MarshallerFactory
[INFO]             Invoking generator org.jboss.errai.marshalling.rebind.MarshallersGenerator
[INFO]                Generating Marshallers Bootstrapper...
[INFO]          Rebinding org.jboss.errai.marshalling.client.api.MarshallerFactory
[INFO]             Invoking generator org.jboss.errai.marshalling.rebind.MarshallersGenerator
[INFO]                Generating Marshallers Bootstrapper...
[INFO]          Rebinding org.jboss.errai.marshalling.client.api.MarshallerFactory
[INFO]             Invoking generator org.jboss.errai.marshalling.rebind.MarshallersGenerator
[INFO]                Generating Marshallers Bootstrapper...
[INFO]          Rebinding org.jboss.errai.marshalling.client.api.MarshallerFactory
[INFO]             Invoking generator org.jboss.errai.marshalling.rebind.MarshallersGenerator
[INFO]                Generating Marshallers Bootstrapper...
[INFO]          Rebinding org.jboss.errai.marshalling.client.api.MarshallerFactory
[INFO]             Invoking generator org.jboss.errai.marshalling.rebind.MarshallersGenerator
[INFO]                Generating Marshallers Bootstrapper...
[INFO]    Scanning for additional dependencies: D:\Project\7th Semester\JBoss Developer Studio\Workspace\gwt-kitchensink\target\.generated\org\jboss\tools\gwt\kitchensink\client\shared\_MemberValidator.java
[INFO]       Adding '1' new generated units
[INFO]          Validating newly compiled units
[INFO]             Ignored 1 unit with compilation errors in first pass.
[INFO] Compile with -strict or with -logLevel set to TRACE or DEBUG to see all errors.
[INFO]    [ERROR] Errors in 'D:\Project\7th Semester\JBoss Developer Studio\Workspace\gwt-kitchensink\target\.generated\org\jboss\tools\gwt\kitchensink\client\shared\_MemberValidatorImpl.java'
[INFO]       [ERROR] Line 431:  The method validate(GwtValidationContext<T>, Set<ConstraintViolation<T>>, Member, V, ConstraintValidator<A,? super V>, ConstraintDescriptorImpl<A>, Class<?>[]) in the type AbstractGwtSpecificValidator<Member> is not applicable for the arguments (GwtValidationContext<T>, Set<ConstraintViolation<T>>, Member, String, SizeValidatorForArraysOfLong, ConstraintDescriptorImpl<Size>, Class<?>[])
[INFO]       [ERROR] Line 455:  The method validate(GwtValidationContext<T>, Set<ConstraintViolation<T>>, Member, V, ConstraintValidator<A,? super V>, ConstraintDescriptorImpl<A>, Class<?>[]) in the type AbstractGwtSpecificValidator<Member> is not applicable for the arguments (GwtValidationContext<T>, Set<ConstraintViolation<T>>, Member, String, SizeValidatorForArraysOfLong, ConstraintDescriptorImpl<Size>, Class<?>[])
[INFO]       [ERROR] Line 479:  The method validate(GwtValidationContext<T>, Set<ConstraintViolation<T>>, Member, V, ConstraintValidator<A,? super V>, ConstraintDescriptorImpl<A>, Class<?>[]) in the type AbstractGwtSpecificValidator<Member> is not applicable for the arguments (GwtValidationContext<T>, Set<ConstraintViolation<T>>, Member, String, SizeValidatorForArraysOfLong, ConstraintDescriptorImpl<Size>, Class<?>[])
[INFO]       [ERROR] Line 480:  The method validate(GwtValidationContext<T>, Set<ConstraintViolation<T>>, Member, V, ConstraintValidator<A,? super V>, ConstraintDescriptorImpl<A>, Class<?>[]) in the type AbstractGwtSpecificValidator<Member> is not applicable for the arguments (GwtValidationContext<T>, Set<ConstraintViolation<T>>, Member, String, DigitsValidatorForNumber, ConstraintDescriptorImpl<Digits>, Class<?>[])
[INFO]    [ERROR] Cannot proceed due to previous errors
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 54.449s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Oct 12 19:19:29 IST 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 10M/25M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:2.4.0:compile (default) on project gwt-kitchensink: Command [[
[ERROR] C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\java -Xmx512m -classpath "D:\Project\7th Semester\JBoss Developer Studio\Workspace\gwt-kitchensink\src\main\java;D:\Project\7th Semester\JBoss Developer Studio\Workspace\gwt-kitchensink\src\main\resources;D:\Project\7th Semester\JBoss Developer Studio\Workspace\gwt-kitchensink\target\classes;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\javax\enterprise\cdi-api\1.0-SP4\cdi-api-1.0-SP4.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\org\jboss\spec\javax\interceptor\jboss-interceptors-api_1.1_spec\1.0.1.Final\jboss-interceptors-api_1.1_spec-1.0.1.Final.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\javax\inject\javax.inject\1\javax.inject-1.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\org\jboss\spec\javax\transaction\jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec\1.0.1.Final\jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec-1.0.1.Final.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\org\jboss\spec\javax\annotation\jboss-annotations-api_1.1_spec\1.0.1.Final\jboss-annotations-api_1.1_spec-1.0.1.Final.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\org\jboss\spec\javax\ws\rs\jboss-jaxrs-api_1.1_spec\1.0.0.Final\jboss-jaxrs-api_1.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\javax\persistence\hibernate-jpa-2.0-api\1.0.1.Final\hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\org\jboss\spec\javax\ejb\jboss-ejb-api_3.1_spec\1.0.2.Final\jboss-ejb-api_3.1_spec-1.0.2.Final.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\javax\validation\validation-api\1.0.0.GA\validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-validator\4.2.0.Final\hibernate-validator-4.2.0.Final.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-validator\4.2.0.Final\hibernate-validator-4.2.0.Final-sources.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\javax\validation\validation-api\1.0.0.GA\validation-api-1.0.0.GA-sources.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\org\jboss\errai\errai-bus\2.0.0.Final\errai-bus-2.0.0.Final.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\org\jboss\errai\errai-common\2.0.0.Final\errai-common-2.0.0.Final.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\org\jboss\errai\reflections\reflections\2.0.0.Final\reflections-2.0.0.Final.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\com\google\guava\guava\10.0.1\guava-10.0.1.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\com\google\code\findbugs\jsr305\1.3.9\jsr305-1.3.9.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\dom4j\dom4j\1.6.1\dom4j-1.6.1.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\xml-apis\xml-apis\1.0.b2\xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\org\jboss\errai\errai-marshalling\2.0.0.Final\errai-marshalling-2.0.0.Final.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\com\google\inject\guice\3.0\guice-3.0.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\aopalliance\aopalliance\1.0\aopalliance-1.0.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\org\mvel\mvel2\2.1.Beta8\mvel2-2.1.Beta8.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.6.1\slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-log4j12\1.6.1\slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\log4j\log4j\1.2.16\log4j-1.2.16.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\org\javassist\javassist\3.15.0-GA\javassist-3.15.0-GA.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\org\jboss\errai\io\netty\netty\4.0.0.Alpha1.errai.r1\netty-4.0.0.Alpha1.errai.r1.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\org\jboss\errai\errai-ioc\2.0.0.Final\errai-ioc-2.0.0.Final.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\org\jboss\errai\errai-codegen\2.0.0.Final\errai-codegen-2.0.0.Final.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\org\jboss\errai\errai-tools\2.0.0.Final\errai-tools-2.0.0.Final.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\hsqldb\hsqldb\1.8.0.7\hsqldb-1.8.0.7.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\org\jboss\errai\errai-cdi-client\2.0.0.Final\errai-cdi-client-2.0.0.Final.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\org\jboss\errai\errai-javax-enterprise\2.0.0.Final\errai-javax-enterprise-2.0.0.Final.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\org\jboss\errai\errai-weld-integration\2.0.0.Final\errai-weld-integration-2.0.0.Final.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\com\google\gwt\gwt-user\2.4.0\gwt-user-2.4.0.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\com\google\gwt\gwt-dev\2.4.0\gwt-dev-2.4.0.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-jpamodelgen\1.1.1.Final\hibernate-jpamodelgen-1.1.1.Final.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\com\google\gwt\gwt-user\2.4.0\gwt-user-2.4.0.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\javax\validation\validation-api\1.0.0.GA\validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\javax\validation\validation-api\1.0.0.GA\validation-api-1.0.0.GA-sources.jar;D:\Users\Icemilk\.m2\repository\com\google\gwt\gwt-dev\2.4.0\gwt-dev-2.4.0.jar" com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler -gen "D:\Project\7th Semester\JBoss Developer Studio\Workspace\gwt-kitchensink\target\.generated" -logLevel INFO -style OBF -war "D:\Project\7th Semester\JBoss Developer Studio\Workspace\gwt-kitchensink\src\main\webapp" -localWorkers 4 org.jboss.tools.gwt.kitchensink.KitchenSink
[ERROR] ]] failed with status 1
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Comment: Unrecognized option : Semester\JBoss. Something is wrong with your paths

Comment: Thanks. I'm in middle of a complete reinstall right now (JRE + Dev Studio). Fingers crossed.

Comment: Hello. It [compiled](http://pastebin.com/z02rQ1xC) this time, even with Unrecognized option : Semester\JBoss flag. Still, I'm curious to know the cause.